# Angular2: rendering / reloading a component's template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Ideally I would need to reload / rerender my component's template but if there is a better way to do this I will gladly implement it.

**Desired behavior:**

So, I have a component for a menu element. When *(in another component)* I click an IBO *(some sort of 'client', per say)* is clicked I need to *add* (I'm using `*ngIf`) a new option in the menu that would be *IBO Details* and a child list.

**`IBOsNavigationElement` component (menu component):**

```js
@Component({
    selector: '[ibos-navigation-element]',
    template: `
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-group"></i> <span
                class="menu-item-parent">{{'IBOs' | i18n}}</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
                <a routerLink="/ibos/IBOsMain">{{'IBOs Main' | i18n}} {{id}}</a>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="navigationList?.length > 0">
                <a href="#">{{'IBO Details' | i18n}}</a>
                <ul>
                    <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let navigatedIBO of navigationList">
                        <a href="#/ibos/IboDetails/{{navigatedIBO['id']}}">{{navigatedIBO['name']}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    `
})
export class IBOsNavigationElement implements OnInit {
    private navigationList = <any>[];


    constructor(private navigationService: NavigationElementsService) {
        this.navigationService.updateIBOsNavigation$.subscribe((navigationData) => {
                this.navigationList.push(navigationData);
                log.d('I received this Navigation Data:', JSON.stringify(this.navigationList));
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Initially, `navigationList` will be empty `[]`, because the user didn't click any IBO *(client)*, but as soon as an IBO is clicked the list will be populated and, therefore, I need the new option to appear in the menu.

With this code, when I click an IBO, the `<li>` element and it's children are created but: **I only see the `<li>` element.**

**Issue:**

The menu option is generated but not proccessed by the layout styles. It needs to be initialized with all the elements in order to know how to display the menu options.

**I need to reload the template of that component in order to display correctly the menu.**

**NOTE:**

If I use the template without the `*ngIf`, works well but I would have from the first moment an *IBO Details* option that has no sense, because no IBO has been clicked when initialized.

```js
template: `
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-group"></i> <span
                class="menu-item-parent">{{'IBOs' | i18n}}</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
                <a routerLink="/ibos/IBOsMain">{{'IBOs Main' | i18n}} {{id}}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">{{'IBO Details' | i18n}}</a>
                <ul>
                    <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let navigatedIBO of navigationList">
                        <a href="#/ibos/IboDetails/{{navigatedIBO['id']}}">{{navigatedIBO['name']}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    `
```

**Desired Output:**

Before clicking anything (on init):

[image]

After I clicked an IBO *(client)*:

[image]

**Update 1:**

To clarify what I meant with:

> The menu option is generated but not proccessed by the layout styles

If, my menu component is initialized without the `*ngIf`:

```js
<li>
    <a href="#">{{'IBO Details' | i18n}}</a>
        <ul>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let navigatedIBO of navigationList">
                <a href="#/ibos/IboDetails/{{navigatedIBO['id']}}">{{navigatedIBO['name']}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

Then the layout styles can generate the menu output *(see images)* according to this structure:

```js
<li>
   <a>
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor>
         <a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

And therefore add the `+` symbol and the submenu behavior, etc.

But, if it's initialized without all the elements (when `*ngIf` is `false` the `<li>` and it's children are not rendered so the layout does not take them into account to draw/create the menu) and these elements are added **after** the rendering, then they will exist in source code, but we won't be able to see them in the menu because:

- No `+` created
- No submenu behavior

Comment: "the menu option is generated but not proccessed by the layout styles" What do you mean ? Reloading the component sounds like a bad idea and a perf killer.

Comment: @n00dl3 Sorry, I am very bad at explaining myself. I updated the question. Short story: Menu is drawed by the layout (.js, .css, etc.) according to elements that exist when rendering the template. If there are missing elements when rendering and are added later on, they will not be *processed* by the layout and we won't see the output in the menu. That's why I need to re-render the template with the `*ngIf` being `true`, so the layout takes into account all the elements *(those inside the `<li *ngIf>`)* and will render properly the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working!

So, my problem was:

**When the new HTML elements are generated *(with `*ngIf`)* they don't get displayed because they don't get *processed* the same way as the other menu elements do.**

So I asked how to reload or re-render the template with all the *'new'* elements... But I did not find where to reload a component or a component's template. As instead, **I applied the logic that process the menu to my updated template.**

*(If you want the short story version, go at the bottom and read the **Summary**)*

So, I dived into my template's deepest logic and created a directive to render the menu:

**MenuDirective (directive)**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[menuDirective]'
})
export class MenuDirective implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  constructor(private menu: ElementRef,
            private router: Router,
            public layoutService: LayoutService) {
    this.$menu = $(this.menu.nativeElement);
  }

  // A lot of boring rendering of layout

  ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.renderSubMenus(this.$menu);
    }

  renderSubMenus(menuElement) {
            menuElement.find('li:has(> ul)').each((i, li) => {
                let $menuItem = $(li);
                let $a = $menuItem.find('>a');
                let sign = $('<b class="collapse-sign"><em class="fa fa-plus-square-o"/></b>');
                $a.on('click', (e) => {
                    this.toggle($menuItem);
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }).append(sign);
            });
    }
}
```

So here I create the menu directive that renders the layout of the menu according to the existing html elements. And, as you can see, **I isolated the behavior that processes the menu elements** adding the `+` icon, creating the submenu feature, etc...: `renderSubMenus()`.

**How does `renderSubMenus()` behave:**

It loops through the DOM elements of the `nativeElement` passed as parameter and applies the logic to display the menu in the correct way.

**menu.html**

```
<ul menuDirective>    
    <li ibos-navigation-element></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span
                            class="menu-item-parent">{{'Orders' | i18n}}</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
                <a routerLink="/orders/ordersMain">{{'Orders' | i18n}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>        
</ul>
```

And that would be how I build the menu.

Now let's see the `IBOsNavigationElement` component, that is included in the menu with the attribute `[ibos-navigation-element]`.

**IBOsNavigationElement (component)**

```
@Component({
    selector: '[ibos-navigation-element]',
    template: `
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-group"></i> <span
                class="menu-item-parent">{{'IBOs' | i18n}}</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="renderMe">
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
                <a routerLink="/ibos/IBOsMain">{{'IBOs Main' | i18n}} {{id}}</a>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="navigationList?.length > 0">
                <a href="#">{{'IBO Details' | i18n}}</a>
                <ul>
                    <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let navigatedIBO of navigationList">
                        <a href="#/ibos/IboDetails/{{navigatedIBO['id']}}">{{navigatedIBO['name']}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    `
})
export class IBOsNavigationElement implements OnInit, DoCheck {
    private $menuElement: any;
    private navigationList = <any>[];
    private menuRendered: boolean = false;

    constructor(private navigationService: NavigationElementsService, private menuDirective: MenuDirective, private menuElement: ElementRef) {
        this.$menuElement = $(this.menuElement.nativeElement);

        this.navigationService.updateIBOsNavigation$.subscribe((navigationData) => {
                this.navigationList.push(navigationData);
                log.d('I received this Navigation Data:', JSON.stringify(this.navigationList));
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
        if (this.navigationList.length > 0 && !this.menuRendered) {
            log.er('calling renderSubMenus()');
            this.menuDirective.renderSubMenus(this.$menuElement.find('ul.renderMe'));
            this.menuRendered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, so what have I done different here? Several things...

1. I import the directive `MenuDirective` so I can call its `renderSubMenus()` method.
2. I use `ElementRef` and `find()` to select the block of code that I want to send to `this.menuDirective.renderSubMenus()`. I find it through its `class`, see: `this.$menuElement.find('ul.renderMe')`.
3. I implement Angular's [DoCheck](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck) hook to detect the changes that I want and apply logic to that change event. See `ngDoCheck()` method where I check if the list  `navigationList` is populated and if I have already rendered this block of code *(I had issues because was rendering too many times and I had like 6 `+` buttons: disaster)*.

**Summary:**

To *'reload'* the template:

1. I created a directive with a method **that applies the logic that usually occurs on init**.
2. I instance that directive in the component that I want to reload.
3. With `ElementRef` I get the portion of template that I want to *'reload'*.
4. I choose when I want to apply the *'reload'* method, in my case I did it with `ngDoCheck()`. You can call that method whenever you want.
5. I call the directive's *'reload*' method passing as parameter the portion of code within my template that I want to reload *(I could have passed the entire template if I wanted)*.
6. **The method will apply to the portion of template that I sent the same logic that would have applied if I instanced the component with the hidden elements by `*ngIf`**.

So, technically, **I did not reload the component**. **I applied to the component's template the same logic that would have been applied if I reloaded it.**

Answer (score 4):

Angular has two change detection strategies:

- The default strategy, that automatically detects changes in the model and re-render the components accordingly.
- OnPush, that only re-renders the component when you explicitly tell it to do
  so.
  See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectionStrategy-enum.html

The OnPush strategy can have a better performance when you have several elements on a page or when you want to have more control over the rendering process.

In order to use this strategy, you have to declare it in your component:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[ibos-navigation-element]',
    template: `...`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

And inject in your constructor:

```
constructor(
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {}
```

When you want to fire the change detection so the component can be re-rendered
(in your case, right after a new IBO/client is added to the model), call:

```
this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
```

Check the live demo from the official tutorial: http://plnkr.co/edit/GC512b?p=preview

If the problem is not about change detection, but related to CSS/SCSS styling,
bear in mind that in Angular 2 each component has its own set of CSS classes and
they're not "inherited" by the "children" elements. They're completely isolated
from each another. One solution could be the creation of global CSS/SCSS styles.

Comment: Hi! I applied what you put on your answer but it's not working well. I will research this approach. CSS is not the problem, is just that the menu has to have all it's *possible* elements in order to render it fully. If we *add* elements on runtime they won't be rendered as it's supposed to and, therefore, we won't see them in the menu.

Comment: Hey! I finally got it working! I had to do quite a work around to *reload* the component, I posted an answer. I checked some `ChangeDetectionStrategy` documentation, very interesting! Thanks for your reply, you have my +1. Have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges-anchor) - it works much like $scope.$digest() from Angular 1.

Note: ChangeDetectorRef must be injected into the component.

Comment: But this detects change in the model, doesn't render or reload my component or it's template. I can detect model changes with my current code, but the problem is that the template has to be processed again in order to *create* the menu layout with the new menu elements. Check the **NOTE** section at OP. Anyways, thanks for the answer bro! ;)