# Angular 2 (4) reload template from back-end

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using some back-end rendered templates in Angular 4 app. And after login I need to reload these templates. Could please someone help with this?
I tried something like

```
import { Component, Compiler  } from '@angular/core';

this.compiler.clearCache();

this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(SharedModule);
```

And I see, that template reloads in the Network tool, but Angular component does't render.

Comment: You need to rerender all templates o just X templates?

Comment: @SrAxi, all templates. But I will appreciate any solution.

Comment: Another question, is it load templates dynamically? Or reload existing (pre loaded) templates?

Comment: @SrAxi, just reload.

Comment: Can you use a route and reload the route ?

Comment: @Milad, hm, after login it is redirect to some page, so yes. But how about top navigation? Could you please clarify your suggestion?

Comment: You can use ReuseStrategy in your route and make force it to recreate the the component

Answer (score 1):

I could not find how to reload a template myself, but I found a *workaround*:

Using [DoCheck()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck).

**Explanation:**

1. I basically understand how my component works, what it does `onInit()` and store that behavior in a directive or method.
2. With `DoCheck()` I am constantly listening to model changing and as soon as the model that I am interested on changes, I trigger that directive or method with the functionality of the component. And therefore, the component *sort of* rerenders.

I implemented this here: [Angular2: rendering / reloading a component's template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43395808/angular2-rendering-reloading-a-components-template)

See my answer, I know it's long, but basically what I did was rerender my menu component when I wanted.

I hope this can be useful... Good Luck!